# Fundamental solution of heat equation in a ball with homogeneous Dirichlet boundary condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, fundamental-solution

I have this particular instance of the Heat Equation: Find u such that

$$\label{eq:Neumann_parabolico}
\left\lbrace \begin{array}{rl}
u_t + \Delta u = 0 & \mbox{in } B(0,1)\times (0,T], \\
u = 0 & \mbox{in } \partial B(0,1) \times (0,T],\\
u(\cdot,0) = \delta_0 & \mbox{in } B(0,1),
\end{array} \right.
$$
for some final $T>0$. Here $B(0,1) \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is the unitary ball centered at 0, and $\delta_0$ is the Dirac delta function.

My question: Is there a closed-form expression for the solution $u(x,y,t)$?

I tried to use the fact that $u$ should have radial symetry, but I didn't succeed...

Comment: What did you get writing out the pde in spherical coordinates?

Comment: Only the equation in shperical coortinated... not much. I used the radial laplacian, $\Delta_r u = \frac{1}{r} \partial r (r u_r)$ and replaced B(0,1) by (-1,1). Then I got stuck there, I don't know how to deal with the delta type initial data.

Comment: I started to give a hint but realized it was for Laplace's equation. My mistake. I'll check back later and if you still need a hint I'll lend a hand.

Comment: Not (-1,1), $(0,1)$!

Comment: You have $u_t = r^{-1}(ru_r)_r = 0$ in the ball. Separate the variables, $u(t, r) = T(t)R(r)$, to get $T'/T = -\lambda$ and $r^2R'' + rR' - \lambda r^2 R = 0$. The latter is satisfied by the modified Bessel functions $I_0$ and $K_0$. The boundary condition $R(1) = 0$ will limit your values of $\lambda$.

Comment: Typo in that last one, “${} = 0$ in the ball.”

Comment: Using Bessel functions seems to be a good idea. But I think there is a problem if we separate variables. We should have $T(t)R(r) \to \delta_0$ when $t \to 0$... and this doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: Yes, it was my mistake latter, I mean $(0,1)$ instead of $(-1,1)$, thanks!